# Magento 2 homepage bestseller, latest and most viewed products

Tags: magento-2.1

How i can add these magento 2 homepage? bestseller, latest and most viewed products. I use version magento 2.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by including block in the home page content.

Go to Content -> Pages from admin panel, 
Select the page
and paste the block of featured/latest product over there in the content section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Magento widgets, to be more specific `Catalog Product List` widget, you can select a specific category or add different conditions